# Как можно писать в лог результат выполнения SQL скрипта?

Tags: sql, oracle, логирование, oracle11g, sqlplus

Использую для выполнения на удаленной машине .bat, который вызывает SQL*Plus и выполняет скрипт. В лог пишется только результат выполнения, в виде сообщения, что столько то строк задействовано, или если произошла ошибка, то код ошибки.

Текст .bat:

```
SET NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251
    
call sqlplus sys/pass@tnsalias as sysdba @restartQueuesSystem.sql >restartQueuesSystem.log
    
pause
    
exit
```

Где:

- `restartQueuesSystem.sql` это файл со скриптом
- `restartQueuesSystem.log` файл содержащий лог выполнения, который пишет сам SQL*Plus

Как можно настроить запись лога в SQL*Plus или модернизировать скрипт так, чтобы в логе писался сам результат выполнения?

Например:
В `restartQueuesSystem.sql` записано `select * from table;`.
Тогда в `restartQueuesSystem.log` я хочу видеть не только уведомление о выполнении, но и результат выполнения запроса `select * from table;`.

Comment: cat restartQueuesSystem.sql >> restartQueuesSystem.log

Comment: и что получился в этом случае, прокоментируйте

Comment: Вывод команды cat допишется  в конец файла

Comment: А что сейчас выводится в лог? Могли бы вы дать пример содержимого restartQueuesSystem.sql и того, что он выводит. Не совсем понятно, что вы понимаете под:  _уведомление о выполнении_ и _результат выполнения_. Пока как описанно в вопросе, всё и так должно записываться в лог и дальнейшие действия не требуются.

Comment: Спасибо за то, что приняли ответ. Попробуйте,  если появются вопросы, обращайтесь.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpqr/index.html#SQPQR101).
Многие команды описанные в [гл. 12 SQL*Plus Command Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SQL-Plus-command-reference.html#GUID-177F24B7-D154-4F8B-A05B-7568079800C6) служат для управления выводом при выполнении SQL предложений в скрипте.

**Рабочий пример для начала**

example.bat:

```
SET NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251

sqlplus -s -l user/pass@dbserver:1521/service @example.sql > example.log

pause
```

example.sql:

```sql
whenever sqlerror exit failure rollback
set feedback on timing on

prompt
prompt ## creating table ...
create table items as
    select rownum id, 'item '||rownum item
    from xmlTable ('1 to 3')

run

prompt
prompt ## updating table ...
update items set item=item||'**' 
where id=2

run

prompt
prompt ## querying table ...
select *
from items

run

prompt
prompt ## droping table ...
drop table items

run
exit
```

При запуске из CMD терминала:

```
> example.bat
```

будет создан следующий лог файл, содержащий команды и результаты их выполнения:

```
## creating table ...
  1  create table items as
  2  select rownum id, 'item '||rownum item
  3*     from xmlTable ('1 to 3')

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.33

## updating table ...
  1  update items set item=item||'**'
  2* where id=2

1 row updated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02

## querying table ...
  1  select *
  2* from items

    ID ITEM
---------- ---------------------------------------------
     1 item 1
     2 item 2**
     3 item 3

3 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.01

## droping table ...
  1* drop table items

Table dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.27
```